# LinkedList inside shared memory

Tags: c, linked-list, shared-memory

I'm trying to share a linked list inside shared memory but I'm having some issues when using `fork()`, without `fork()` it works perfectly but I must have at least a child process.

If there aren't children it works but when I create a child process and use `addValue` function the result is segmentation fault.

The code is not so good because of a lot of changes.
I've tried to use `malloc` but with processes it cannot be done.

Searching in some forums there are different ideas about share linkedlist but none of them works.

Another doubt that I have is about `shmget()`, I have to pass `sizeof(struct Request)` but sometimes they pass`sizeof(struct Request)*n` if there is a max pool of nodes that the linkedlist can handle but sometimes they use `shmget` with different keys like this code that I wrote. So the other question is: `sizeof()*n` or `size()` with multiple `shmget` keys?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

struct Request{
  int value;
  struct Request *next;
}Request;

void errorHandler(char *msg){
  perror(msg);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct Request *getNode(key_t key){
  int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct Request), IPC_CREAT | 0660);
  if(shmid==-1){
    errorHandler("SHMGET7");
  }

  struct Request *req = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
  if(req==(void *)-1){
    errorHandler("SHMAT9");
  }

  return req;
}

void addValue(key_t headKey, key_t newKey, int value){
  struct Request *head = getNode(headKey);
  while(head->next!=NULL){
    head = head->next;
  }
  struct Request *node = getNode(newKey);
  node->value = value;
  node->next = NULL;

  head->next = node;
}

void printNodes(key_t key){
  struct Request *head = getNode(key);
  while(head!=NULL){
    printf("%d\n", head->value);
    head = head->next;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  key_t key = 1234;
  struct Request *req = getNode(key);
  req->value = -1;
  req->next = NULL;

  key_t newKey = 250;
  addValue(key, newKey, 100);
  newKey = 251;
  addValue(key, newKey, 101);

  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid==-1){
      errorHandler("FORK");
    }else if(pid==0){
      newKey = 252+i;
      addValue(key, newKey, 101);

      exit(0);
    }

    sleep(1);
  }

  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    wait(NULL);
  }

  printNodes(key);
  printf("end\n");

  return 0;
}
```

For `shmdt` I've got to loop linkedlist and `shmdt` every node?

Comment: are you interested by my answer ? Is it explain and solves your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there aren't children it works but when I create a child process and use addValue function the result is segmentation fault.

An address returned by `shmat(<id>, NULL, <flg>)` is only valid for the current process, to use it in an other process has an undefined behavior.

For the first *fork* the list contains valid addresses coming from the parent because the  child inherits the attached shared memory segments. But at the second turn (*i* valuing 1) the second *fork* try to use an address which is not valid for it nor the main process later in `printNodes` because coming from the first *fork* and only valid for it. For the same reason supposing the main process is able to get the address return by `shmap` for the second *fork*, that address cannot be dereferenced too.

---

> I have to pass sizeof(struct Request) but sometimes ...

this is the right size because you want to allocate one cell, using `malloc` the needed size is the same.

---

One way to solve your problem is to use for `next` the key rather than an address not valid out of the current process and its children.

Doing the minimal changes from your code, using the key 0 for the NULL pointer, the modified definitions are :

```
struct Request{
  int value;
  key_t next;
} Request;
```

and

```
void addValue(key_t headKey, key_t newKey, int value){
  struct Request *head = getNode(headKey);

  while(head->next!=0){
    headKey = head->next;
    head = getNode(headKey);
  }

  struct Request *node = getNode(newKey);

  node->value = value;
  node->next = 0;

  head->next = newKey;
}

void printNodes(key_t key) {
  while (key != 0) {
    struct Request *head = getNode(key);

    printf("%d\n", head->value);
    key = head->next;
  }
}
```

and at the beginning or *main* :

```
req->next = 0;
```

After that, compilation and execution (I added `#include <sys/wait.h>`) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall l.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
i=0
i=1
-1
100
101
101
101
end
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```